# match special characters in url in nginx

Tags: nginx, regex

I ran dotdotpwn to test transversal attacks on a web server using nginx/nasxi/doxsi and the only "successes" were urls that started with a question mark. No big deal since they just defaulted to the index.html, but as a learning process, I want to flag such requests with a 403. At the moment I am serving static pages.

This is my attempt to snag such requests:

```
location ~ [\?=+-] {
         return 403;
       }
```

This doesn't work. (If it did, would I be posting here? ;-) )

The only non-alphanumeric I use is the underscore, so ultimately I'd like to snag all the special characters.

Answer (score 1):

So the nginx documentation says that the [location directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) matches the request URI.

The way nginx defines URI is as the part after the domain and before URL parameters. So for instance `/index.html` or `/foo/bar/index.php` might be URIs. For your purpose this means a location directive will never match the ? unless it's URL encoded as part of the URI rather than for the URL parameters.

If you really want to do this you will have to do

```
if ($request_uri ~ regex) { 
    return 444;
}
```

Comment: This worked for my situation as well. I was trying to use location instead b/c of the who "if is evil" belief, but following Nginx suggestions, doing an immediate redirect or return from within the if block should be harmless. I think this worked vs the location directive because the location directive only considered the urldecoded version of %21 before applying the regex so it would never match. Vs just matching against the raw $request_uri.